# Maven: why child project looks for parent's repo in its own directory

Tags: maven

I have a Maven child project in a directory `child`. I have also a parent project `local-lib` in the directory `child/local-lib` which contains a repository with jars. This is, this, the full directory structure:

```
child/ # child project
    local-lib # parent project
        repo # local repo
        pom.xml # configuration of the parent project
    pom.xml # configuration of the child project
```

The local repository is declared in `child/local-lib/pom.xml` as

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

The child project has `child/pom.xml` where it refers to its parent as follows:

```
    <parent>
            <groupId>someGroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>local-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
            <relativePath>./local-lib</relativePath>
    </parent>
```

When I type `mvn clean install` in the child project, that is, in the directory `child`, the child project attempts to search for a non-existing repository `child/repo`, instead of `child/local-lib/repo`. However, replacing `${project.basedir}` in `child/local-lib/pom.xml` with the full path to `child/local-lib` on my disk makes the child project use the correct repository `child/local-lib/repo`. This in turn, placed in `child/local-lib/pom.xml` as before, but with additional `local-lib`:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repo</id>
            <url>file:///${project.basedir}/local-lib/repo</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
```

works this time correctly if I use maven from the directory `child`, but not if I use directly `child/local-lib/pom.xml` from `child/local-lib`. The latter creates a path with `local-lib` included twice.

Why, in the case of a repository definition, `${project.basedir}` points sometimes to the directory of a child `pom.xml`, instead of its own `pom.xml`? Is there a property which unconditionally points to `pom.xml`'s own directory? If not, what is the motivation behind that?

Comment: Why not use a repository manager like Nexus or Artifactory and manage the repositories in the `settings.xml`?

Comment: I am new to Maven. I do not know these managers but I might do it eventually as you say. Thank you for telling me. But still, I would like to understand the concept of ${project.basedir} in Maven.

Comment: Can you show a full directory structure of your project... furthermore it would be helpful having an example project on github or alike...

Comment: Apart from that the `local-lib`  is the question why do you need that ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I added the full directory structure. I need `local-lib` as a bridge to a number of projects which use Ant instead of Maven ant to other jars which do not exist in the Maven web repo.

Comment: I would set up a Nexus or Artifactory server (which is easy) and deploy the Ant build results to that server.

Comment: As J Fabian Meier already mentioned use a repository manager and use them as usual dependencies makes everything easier ...

Comment: For a multi module build you don't need to define a local repository. You can build a multi module build via `mvn package` or if you need to have integration tests (assumed you have configured maven-failsafe-plugin) `mvn verify` and if you want to deploy all artifacts to a remote repository (repository manager) `mvn deploy`.... Use the local cache `$HOME/.m2/repository` and do not try to build your own setup...